# How far should one take e-mail address validation?

Tags: regular-expressions, validation, user-interface

I'm wondering how far people should take the validation of e-mail address. My field is primarily web-development, but this applies anywhere.

I've seen a few approaches:

- simply checking if there is an "@" present, which is dead simple but of course not that reliable.
- a more complex regex test for standard e-mail formats
- a [full regex](http://code.iamcal.com/php/rfc822/full_regexp.txt) against [RFC 2822](http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc2822.html) - the problem with this is that often an e-mail address might be valid but it is probably not what the user meant
- DNS validation
- SMTP validation

As many people might know (but many don't), e-mail addresses can have a lot of strange variation that most people don't usually consider (see [RFC 2822 3.4.1](http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc2822.html)), but you have to think about the goals of your validation: are you simply trying to ensure that an e-mail message can be sent to an address, or that it is what the user probably meant to put in (which is unlikely in a lot of the more obscure cases of otherwise 'valid' addresses).

An option I've considered is simply giving a warning with a more esoteric address but still allowing the request to go through, but this does add more complexity to a form and most users are likely to be confused.

While DNS validation / SMTP validation seem like no-brainers, I foresee problems where the DNS server/SMTP server is temporarily down and a user is unable to register somewhere, or the user's SMTP server doesn't support the required features.

How might some experienced developers out here handle this? Are there any other approaches than the ones I've listed?

Edit: I completely forgot the most obvious of all, sending a confirmation e-mail! Thanks to answerers for pointing that one out. Yes, this one is pretty foolproof, but it does require extra hassle on the part of everyone involved. The user has to fetch some e-mail, and the developer needs to remember user data before they're even confirmed as valid.

Comment: Personally I'd go with the double regex Warn and Reject strategy followed by an email to confirm ownership of the address.

Comment: The big question is to ask what purpose you are asking for the address.  For instance, if you are going to send a validation email to the user then a very simple check should suffice, since presumably the user is motivated to give a valid address.

Comment: Related information with specification links https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Email_address

Answer (score 89, accepted):

There is no 100% reliable way of confirming a valid email address other than sending an email to user and and waiting for a response, like most forums.

I would go with the simple "@" validation rule and then email the user to confirm their email address.

Although, this is my personal opinion... I await other suggestions.

Comment: Totally agree. Either you *really* care about that address, or you don't. I don't see any rationale for half-caring.

Comment: By far the best answer.  _Validate_ the @ then _verify_ the address (with an email) - subtle difference there.

Comment: ...which is why that's what most forums do.

Comment: I agree with  @Billy Bob, that a simple validation followed up by a verification email is the most effective way to prove the email is accurate.

Comment: A “valid” email address may also be going to the wrong person so a validation email is really the only way to be sure. I get a few of those each year when someone mistypes their own email address for mine.

Answer (score 61):

One suggestion: don't reject addresses with a + in them.  It's annoyingly common to reject them, but it's a valid character, and gmail users can use address+label@gmail.com to label and sort incoming mail more easily.

Comment: +1 !!! It seems impossible to filter emails from Facebook, of all sites!

Comment: Can filter without that - just user the sender info

Comment: GMail picked it up from other mail servers.  I believe qmail and postfix popularized it.

Comment: While I agree with the sentiment, this doesn't even begin to answer the question.

Comment: Read this: https://debounce.io/blog/articles/email-syntax-error-explained/

Answer (score 30):

In your post it seems that when you say "SMTP validation" you mean connecting to the server and trying a RCPT TO to see if it's accepted.  Since you differentiate it from actually sending a confirmation email, I assume you want to do it inline with the user actions.  In addition to problems like network issues, DNS failures, etc, gray listing can wreak havoc with this method.  Method's vary, but essentially gray listing always defers the first attempt to deliver to recipient per connecting IP.  As I said, this can vary, some hosts might reject invalid addresses at first attempt and only defer valid addresses, but there's no reliable way to sort out the different implementations programmatically.

The only way you'll ever be sure that an address is valid and is submitted by its owner who really does want it used for your application is to send a verification email.  Well, as long as it doesn't get spam filtered I guess =).

Answer (score 27):

Another weakness of using a regex for email validation is that it's almost impossible to catch all the valid [top-level domains](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Internet_top-level_domains) while rejecting all the invalid ones.

For instance, the basic email regex in Jeff Atwood's reply:

> \b[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+.[A-Z]{2,4}\b

will accept any TLD of two to four characters. So, for example, .spam will be accepted, but .museum and .travel (both valid TLDs) will be rejected.

Just one more reason it's better to just look for the @, and send a confirmation email.

Answer (score 27):

With international domain names **almost** everything is possible:

- Håkan.Söderström@malmö.se
- punnycode@XN--0ZWM56D.XN--HGBK6AJ7F53BBA
- 试@例子.测试.مثال.آزمایشی

If you want to do any tests you should first convert it to punycode.

Without punycode all you should do is to test that there:

- is at least one @
- is at least one character in the local part
- is at least one dot in the domain part
- is at least four characters in the domain (assuming that no-one has an address at the tld, that the tld is at least 2 chars)

```js
function isEmail(address) {
    var pos = address.lastIndexOf("@");
    return pos > 0 && (address.lastIndexOf(".") > pos) && (address.length - pos > 4);
}
```

Comment: If you want to use javascript to convert to punycode you can use the code in the following answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/183485/can-anyone-recommend-a-good-free-javascript-for-punycode-to-unicode-conversion/301287#301287

Comment: True enough - then ensuring the @ sign might be the only way to be sure it "looks" like an email address.

Answer (score 19):

You're best off just checking for simple things like @ and . in JavaScript, and then actually send them a verification to their email. If they verify their account, you have yourself a valid email address. That way you know for sure you have a working address, and you don't have to be too bossy in the form.

Comment: This is a great solution. Here is a regexp to look for a @ followed by a dot: `/.+@.+\..+/`

Answer (score 11):

Use an open-source validator which doesn't give false negatives. Zero effort for you and robust validation for your app.

I've now collated test cases from Cal Henderson, Dave Child, Phil Haack, Doug Lovell and RFC 3696. 158 test addresses in all.

I ran all these tests against all the validators I could find. The comparison is here: http://www.dominicsayers.com/isemail

I'll try to keep this page up-to-date as people enhance their validators. Thanks to Cal, Dave and Phil for their help and co-operation in compiling these tests and constructive criticism of [my own validator](http://code.google.com/p/isemail/source/browse/PHP/trunk/is_email.php).

People should be aware of the [errata against RFC 3696](http://www.rfc-editor.org/errata_search.php?rfc=3696) in particular. Three of the canonical examples are in fact invalid addresses. And the maximum length of an address is 254 or 256 characters, **not** 320.

Comment: Link to comparison is down :(

Answer (score 10):

On consideration from the answers (since I completely forgot about confirmation e-mails) it seems to me like a suitable compromise for a low-friction solution would be to:

1. Use regex to check that the e-mail address looks valid, and give a warning if it is more obscure but avoid rejecting outright.
2. Use SMTP validation to ensure that the e-mail address is valid.
3. If SMTP validation *fails* then -- and *only then* -- use a confirmation e-mail as a last resort. Confirmation e-mails seem to require too much interaction outside of your application for them to be considered low friction, but they are a perfect fallback.

Comment: How can you check that a user owns the email address without sending confirmation? For example, lets say they typed in your email address. Wouldn't you be annoyed that the developer decided not to provide a confirmation email and therefore allowed anybody who knows your address to sign you up to their site?

Comment: SMTP validation?   Ask the server if the address exists?  Spam got rid of that long time ago.

Answer (score 6):

[RegexBuddy](http://www.regexbuddy.com/) offers the following email-related regular expressions from its library:

Email address (basic)

```
\b[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4}\b
```

Email address (RFC 2822, simplified)

```
[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\.[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*@(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\.)+[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?
```

But I tend to agree with Peter and SuperJoe's responses; the only real "testing" is actually sending a validation email.

Comment: Your basic email check fails against things like `bob@mydivision.mycompany.com`.  You should also say a case-insensitive match is required as you're only using upper case ASCII.

Comment: Why reject uppercase characters (with the second regex)? Shouldn't be the validation of the local-part up to the receiving MTA? With the exception of white spaces and quotes.

Comment: @dirk as mark noted, you'd apply the "not case sensitive" flag to this regex when running it.

Comment: The basic one is not good as there are several TLD >4 chars.  I'd just make it min 2, no max `{2,}`

Answer (score 4):

I've worked at 4 different companies where someone at the help desk got yelled at by someone named O'Malley or O'Brien or some other e-mail address with an apostrophe. As suggested previously, not all regex's will catch everything, but save yourself some hassle and accept an apostrophe without generating a warning.

--
bmb

Comment: Amen to that. The same goes for the hash sign (#), by the way.

Comment: Just because peoples' names don't contain hash marks doesn't mean that they're not valid in email addresses.

Answer (score 3):

@[Mike](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3232/how-far-should-one-take-e-mail-address-validation#3263) - I think that part of the reason why confirmation emails are sent is not only to ensure that the email address is valid, but that it is accessible by the user who submitted it. A person could easily put in a one-letter typo in the email address that would lead to a different, valid email address, but that would still be an error as it would be the *wrong* address.

Answer (score 3):

On some sites developed at places I have worked at, we have always used confirmation emails. However, it was surprisingly common for the users to mistype their email address in ways that could not possibly have worked, and then keep waiting for the confirmation email which would not come. Adding ad-hoc code (or, for the domain name part, DNS verification) to warn the user in these cases could be a good idea.

The common cases I have seen:

- Dropping a letter on the middle of the domain name, or several other simple typo variants.
- TLD confusion (for instance, adding a `.br` to a `.com` domain, or dropping the `.br` from a `.com.br` domain).
- Adding a `www.` at the beginning of the local part of an email address (I am not making this up; I saw *several* email addresses of the form `www.username@example.com`).

There were even more bizarre cases; things like a complete *domain name* as the local part, addresses with two `@` (something like `username@domain.tld@example.com`), and so on.

Of course, most of them were still valid RFC-822 addresses, so *technically* you could just let the MTA deal with them. However, warning the user that the email address entered is quite possibly bogus can be helpful, especially if your target audience is not very computer literate.

Comment: Sounds like the problem with those sites was that users were forced to enter information they really didn't understand. Not all sites require e-mail contact with its users, even if it would make things easier for the site.

Comment: I feel like if someone makes an email address with two @'s in it, they simply do not deserve to receive email.

Answer (score 3):

You could take email validation still further to actually test if a mailbox exists. This technique has its drawbacks (development time and also possibility of getting blacklisted for misuse). http://www.webdigi.co.uk/blog/2009/how-to-check-if-an-email-address-exists-without-sending-an-email/

Answer (score 3):

If you want to *verify* an e-mail (i.e. ensure, that the user owns the e-mail address), a confirmation e-mail is the only thing you can do. Then again many people have dedicated spam-addresses or use services like [OneWayMail](http://onewaymail.com/) and if they don't want to give you their actual e-mail address, they won't. So basically you're creating user obstruction.

When it comes to [*validation*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_validation), to ensure, that the user doesn't unintentionally input a wrong e-mail address, it's definitely the right motivation. However, at least for HTML forms (which are by far the most common way of gathering e-mail addresses), it is hardly the right instrument.

For one, you will not be able to recognize typos in the actual "words" of the email address. You have no way of finding out that `back2dso@example.com` is wrong, solely based on the format.
But more importantly, from a user point of view, there's only one (or a hand full) of email addresses you could possibly want to enter. And you've probably already entered it.
So rather than trying to validate an address, you should focus on ensuring, that all browsers recognize the email field and thereby eliminate the need to type in the email address in the first place. Of course this doesn't apply, if you're building the kind of site likely to be hit by users who never entered their e-mail address into their browser before. But I suppose the least of us are in such a position.

Answer (score 2):

I think it depends on what context you're using the email for.  More serious projects require stricter validation but I think for most things sending an email to the provided address with a conformation link will ensure the email address is valid.

Answer (score 2):

Depends on the goal. If you are an ISP and you need to validate that users are creating valid email addresses, go for the Regex that validates against everything possible. If you just want to catch user errors, how about the following pattern:

[All Characters, no spaces] @ [letters and numbers] (.[letters and numbers]) 
where the final group appears at least one time.

The RegEx for this would appear something like this:

```
[\S]+@[\w]+(.[\w-]+)+
```

And then send a confirmation email to be sure.

Comment: There is a typo (unless you only want to allow "w" as the TLD) and it don't match domains with a hyphen (-). This works better:  [\S]+@[\w-]+(.[\w-]+)+

Comment: The dot has to be escaped: `^[\S]+@[\w]+(\.[\w-]+)+$`

Answer (score 2):

All the regex validation in the world won't prevent someone from entering an incorrect or fake email address.  It's just annoying, really.

Comment: Have you ever tried DeBounce [Email Validation Tool](https://debounce.io)? I suggest taking a look at this service.

Answer (score 2):

The most complete and accurate regex I've ever encountered for email validation is the one documented [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20080102113810/http://www.leshazlewood.com/%3Fp%3D5). It is not for the faint of heart; it's complicated enough that it's broken into parts to make it easier for humans to parse (sample code is in Java). But in cases where going all the way with validation is merited, I don't think it gets much better.

In any case, I would suggest that you use unit testing to confirm that your expression covers the cases that you feel are important. That way, as you dink around with it, you can be sure that you haven't broken some case that worked before.

Answer (score 2):

Whatever you choose, I think you need to err on the side of believing that 99% of the time, the user **does** actually know what their email address is. As someone from Australia, I still find very occasionally an oh-so-clever email validation that tells me that I can't possibly have a .com.au domain. It used to happen a lot more in the early days of the internet mind you.

Sending a confirmation email these days is acceptable to users, and is also useful in terms of opt-in as well as validating their supplied address.

Answer (score 1):

@[Yaakov](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3232/how-far-should-one-take-e-mail-address-validation#3268) (could reply do with some sort of 'replying' here)

> I think that part of the reason why confirmation emails are sent is not only to ensure that the email address is valid, but that it is accessible by the user who submitted it. A person could easily put in a one-letter typo in the email address that would lead to a different, valid email address, but that would still be an error as it would be the wrong address.

I concur, but I'm not sure it's worth it. We also have confirmation fields for that purpose (repeating your e-mail address again). Another situation where the type of site might warrant different approaches.

Additionally, sending a confirmation e-mail itself gives no way of indication to the original user that the address they entered was wrong. After not receiving the confirm e-mail they may just assume your app/site is faulty; at least by allowing the user to immediately start using their account they could correct their e-mail address, particularly if it is displayed in a suitably obvious place.

Answer (score 1):

**Horses for courses.**

All those are valid, complete email verification systems in and of themselves, and for a given website one will be more appropriate (or as good as is warranted) than the others.  In many cases several steps of verification may be useful.

If you're developing a website for a bank, you're going to want snail mail or phone verification on top of all these.

If you're developing a website for a contest you might not want any of them - verify the emails in post processing and if one fails it's too bad for the person who entered it - you might value server performance given a huge crush of people (TV contest, for instance) over making sure that everyone gets validated correctly inline.

## How far should one take email verification?

## *As far as necessary and warranted.*

*And no further (KISS)*

Answer (score 1):

I've seen sites that also guard against people using temporary throwaway spam bucket sites like [Mailinator](http://mailinator.com) or [MyTrashMail](http://mytrashmail.com/), which get around the confirmation e-mail thing.  I'm not saying you should be filtering those out, I'm just saying.

Comment: In what way does it "get around" the e-mail confirmation? Both Mailinator and MyTrashMail will accept subsequent mails to the same address. If the user doesn't bother to check them, that's another story.

Answer (score 1):

What are you trying to catch in your email validation?

Regex validation of email addresses can, at best, verify that the address is syntactically correct and relatively plausible.  It also has the hazard (as already mentioned many times) of possibly rejecting actual, deliverable addresses if the regex isn't quite correct.

SMTP verification can determine that the address is deliverable, subject to the limitations imposed by greylisting or servers which are configured to give out as little information as possible about their users.  You have no way of knowing whether the MTA has only claimed to accept mail for a bogus address, then just dropped it on the floor as part of an anti-spam strategy.

Sending a confirmation message, though, is the *only* way to verify that an address belongs to the user who entered it.  If I'm filling out your form, I can quite easily tell you that my email address is `president@whitehouse.gov`.  A regex will tell you it's syntactically valid, an SMTP RCPT TO will tell you it's a deliverable address, but it sure as hell ain't *my* address.

Answer (score 1):

With the coming of HTML5 at least one new approach is added to the possibilities: the use of the input of type '[email](http://diveintohtml5.org/forms.html#type-email)' which allows [validation](http://diveintohtml5.org/forms.html#validation) on the client side. Current versions of Firefox, Chrome, Safari and Opera do support this (and other browsers just treat it like type=text, so it can be used without problems althoug then you don't have validation of course.)

It can never (as is pointed out a few times) guarantee a workable address, but it may be very beneficial (and eventually replace the server side check) in places where you just need to catch likely user errors.

Comment: The Firefox implementation for the `<input type="email">` HTMLElement: https://dxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/source/dom/html/HTMLInputElement.cpp#6981

Answer (score 0):

**The three main levels of email validation:**

1) regular expression check for a properly formatted email address email@email.com

2) email domain check against MX records to see if the domain name has an email service

3) sending a confirmation email with a confirmation link or code

**Level 1:**

In Visual Studio, you can use the "Regular Expression Validator". And in the "ValidationExpression" property you can click on the "..." button that has a wizard to add in the regular expression format for email addresses.

**Level 2:**

Here is my C# code below to use nslookup to verify whether an email domain has valid MX records. Runs quick and ok on Win 2008 R2 and Win 7.

```cs
using System.Net.Mail;
using System.Diagnostics;

public static bool checkMXRecords(string email) 
    {
        MailAddress addr = new MailAddress(email);
        string domain = addr.Host;

        string command = "nslookup -querytype=mx " + domain;
        ProcessStartInfo procStartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("cmd", "/c " + command);

        procStartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        procStartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;

        procStartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;

        Process proc = new Process();
        proc.StartInfo = procStartInfo;
        proc.Start();
        string result = proc.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();

        if (result.ToLower().Contains("mail exchanger"))
        {
            return true;
        }
        else return false;

     } // checkMXRecords
```

another option is to use the Arsofttools nuget package but it may be slow on Windows Server 2008 R2 as I have experienced but runs quick on Win 7.

**Level 3:**

For email confirmation, you can either generate an email specific hex url (using encryption functions) etc http://domain.com/validateEmail?code=abcd1234 to validate the email address when the user clicks on it. There is no need to store this url in memory.